# Online pronunciation of mathematicians names

Tags: reference-request

I self study mathematics. Since I don't attend lectures and learn by reading books, it happens frequently that I read names of mathematicians that I am not sure of how they should be pronounced. Is there an online resorce that provides pronunciation of mathematicians names ?

Thank you

Comment: @PandaBear Good suggestion but it is not working for Saharon Shelah

Comment: Well, how do you pronounce Amr?

Comment: @WillJagy My name can just be pronounced just by pronouncing every letter appearing in my name in the order they appear in my name. Some names do not satisfy the property that my name satisfies

Comment: Thought I had you there.

Comment: @WillJagy What does this mean ?

Comment: It is mildly humorous, it means I thought you had completely made up the username Amr and that you would be unable to provide a pronunciation for it.

Comment: @WillJagy Ahhh OK :)

Answer (score 2):

[This site](http://pronouncemath.blogspot.co.uk) may be what you are looking for, at least for mostly non-contemporary mathematicians.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has few mathematicians

Comment: Maybe, but 70 of the best! Were you more looking for modern mathematicians?

Answer (score 1):

I thought about it for a while. There are three things you can do-

**(1)** Look up the where the person is from on wikipedia, then put his or her name in google translate, set the language accordingly and then hit listen. It works out quite often.

**(2)** [Frovo](http://www.forvo.com/) claims to be largest pronunciation guide in the world. The pronunciation for Saharon Shelah is not availaible on google translate but it's [on this site.](http://www.forvo.com/word/saharon_shelah/#he)

**(3)** Look up sites similar to *Frovo*. Also, if you can't find the pronunciation of a particular name, you can break it down, and then look it up. A famous person might share the same surname or the first name.

Answer (score 0):

Wkipedia sometimes has an online pronunciation of their name to listen to.  If they have a wikipedia article that is.

Comment: Some Wikipedia articles don't have an online pronounciation such as this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saharon_Shelah